# I want to get (+1) frame in video file in opencvsharp

Tags: c#, opencv

I want to usee absdiff() function for tracking objects and I have to get second frame.

for example, I use capture.queryframe(2134) for get frame 2134th frame. I need get 2135th frame.

how can I do this?

thanks.

Comment: `capture.queryframe(2135)` I guess?

Comment: I use it for explain my question. of course it is not like this. it is  pictureBox1.Image = capture.QueryFrame().ToBitmap();

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you need the second frame, it is better to save it separately from picture box. So, instead of `pictureBox1.Image = capture.QueryFrame().ToBitmap();` I suggest to do somethig like:

```
Image img = capture.QueryFrame().ToBitmap();
pictureBox1.Image = img;
```

And after this separation it is easy to do the following:

```
Image prevImage, currentImage; // define as class members or global variables

// and in the capturing method:
prevImage = currentImage;
currentImage = capture.QueryFrame().ToBitmap();
pictureBox1.Image = img;
```

So, now you have two frames and can do absdiff or whatever you want. But you still have one problem - the first frame. But it is obvious that it is impossible to find any objects in the first frame, so you can initialize `currentImage` in constructor or any initialization method, or just check it in your capture method.